# What to eat during running?

Tags: long-distance-running, eating-habits, energy-drinks, long-distance

In an inteview, Kilian Jornet said that during races at the end he gained 1 kilo, for all he was eating during the race.

```
- A half-liter to one liter per hour.
- Gels every 30 minutes from the Foresthill checkpoint to the finish. 
- I took Aliment Liquide [liquid food] two times.
- Salt pills at one or two an hour for most of the race. 
- And a few sandwiches at aid stations with tomatoes, ham and cheese.
```

How much would I have to eat or drink during long runs?

Comment: This is very highly individual. The only way to find out for yourself is to run and eat different things, and see how they affect you.

Answer (score 1):

Most weight gained during longer runs is water weight - fun fact [you're more likely to drink *too much* water during a long-distance run than not enough.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathon#Water_consumption_dangers) (It's Wikipedia, but it's got a lot of good sources.)

A quick search shows that Kilian Jornet competes in Ultramarathons of 100+ km where maintaining adequate nutrition is difficult mainly for logistic reasons - eating on the run is hard. So he is probably trained to eat what he can, when he can.

How much you need during training and competition is something *you and your coach* need to figure out. If you haven't got a coach and are looking at getting into Ultras, get one. The best advice on what too eat will come from someone well trained who can observe you in training.

**As for your question, what should you *eat* during a race - probably nothing.** Most amateurs run marathons on a big bowl of pasta the night before, some simple carbohydrates in the morning, and adequate water during the race. I'd suggest that if you are asking this question here, in the way you are, this advice will be adequate for you.